# The Myriad of Ways to Create Mobile Chat App with Backend

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I'm new to mobile apps and just trying to get my footing. I'm trying to create a simple messaging/chat app for Android with all the typical features: user accounts, connecting with friends, and chat. The problem is, I have no idea which technology stack to choose from. I've done quite a bit of searching on the topic, starting with "which stack does snapchat use?" I found that it is built upon the Google app engine (GAE). I've seen tutorials where people use Node.js and MongoDB for the backend while utilizing only the Cloud Messaging part of GAE. There are also tutorials utilizing Parse (I think it's the Facebook equivalent to GAE?) and Sinch. Here's my trouble: I don't know which tech stack to use and I'm in general kinda confused as to why there are so many ways to go about doing the same thing. Even though I'm only a beginner at mobile apps, I want to eventually make this chat app into something of professional quality so I can deploy it and actually get user feedback, which means I want to aim for good scalability. I was wondering if you guys had any recommendations on the simplest approach I can take to developing this app and what kind of tools would be most useful.

I'm relatively comfortable with java and have some experience with webdev but only minimal experience with node and mongo.

Comment: because it applies in general to mobile app development

Comment: Try Twilio IP Messaging: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To build a chat application, you will need to have the following:

- Server to store messages and send notifications
- Client to send and receive messages
- Transportation between the client and server

Here are some differences for your options for each component:

**Server**

- Custom (backend language + database; e.g. node + mongo) - This gives you more flexibility and is much cheaper, but you will have to configure all of the routes, models, database connections, and API responses.
- Backend service (e.g. Parse) - They provide you with the database, routes, and responses, leaving you just to define your data. Much faster to implement, but can be more expensive at scale.

**Client**
(not relevant to the tech stack for this question)

**Transportation**

- API Calls - Singular calls that return some information to the client.
- Web Sockets - Persistent channels that allow information to flow back and forth, enabling real-time communication and notifications.

---

For your specific instance, you'll be using Android and web sockets (if you want real-time chat). The last major part of the stack (server) is up to you, but there are some clear advantages to going with a backend service to begin with:

- The service does much of the work, saving you time to focus on the client.
- It provides you simple ways to connect (transportation), enabling you to create an app just from the client-side.

Bottom line: a backend service like Parse will save you lots of time.

The major downside is cost, but by the time your app uses enough data to be expensive, you will be able to replace the backend and have the time to do so.

---

**My Recommendation:**

Use a backend service like [Parse](https://parse.com/) for an app that is heavily focused on the client. If you outgrow the service or really want to do server programming, you can use a node (or other language) framework like the ones mentioned [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-nodejs#web-frameworks). I personally recommend [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) and have been extremely happy with it as it simple, scalable, and yet still allows complex code such as machine learning.

Best of luck on your app-making journey!

Comment: Thank you for the awesome info !

Comment: Although, I did hear that Parse is weak when it comes to scalability, so I think I am going to try and use App Engine.

Comment: Glad I could help! Use whatever you like; just make sure to do the research.